# Geocode on button press - Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/9B84H/1/

```
var current_place;

function autosuggest() {
    var input = document.getElementById('location');
    var options = { types: [], };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            current_place = null;
            alert('Cannot find place');
            return;
        } else {
            current_place = place;
            alert('Place is at:' + place.geometry.location);
        }
    });

}
```

It works perfectly when you click on an option from the autosuggest. However if you just type something in and click search I need it to run the same geocode operation as when you select an option from the autosuggest. How do I do this?

P.s You have to click the search button to activate the autosuggest script

Comment: Sounds like you may have to bind to all links in your result set.  $(a).bind('click',function(){autosuggest-input(selected_value)});  note, this kind of solution would require that you create a passable variable to your function or create a special function for handling linked values.

Answer (score 0):

As `current_place` is GLOBAL it can be accessed outside function

```
var current_place;

function autosuggest() {
var input = document.getElementById('location');
var options = {
    types: [],
};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
        current_place = null;
        alert('Cannot find place');
        return;
    } else {
        current_place = place;
        alert('Place is at:' + place.geometry.location);
        doIt();
    }
});

}
function doIt(){
    alert(current_place.geometry.location);
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9B84H/29/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It doesnt seem to work with the code I tried here: http://jsfiddle.net/9B84H/31/

Comment: You need to toggle autocomplete on or off

Comment: I tried that. It works fine when you click on a result from autocomplete but not when you click search is run the geocoding command.